# ListView ItemTemplate not fill

Tags: xaml, listview, user-controls, uwp

I created a template for ListViewItem.

It does not fill all the spaces.

My template is the following:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="AgendaUWP.Styles.Template.ItemTemplateContatti"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AgendaUWP.Styles.Template"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="100"
d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3" />
        <ColumnDefinition  />
        <ColumnDefinition  />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="CornflowerBlue" Grid.Column="0"  Width="3" Margin="0 0 0 0"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1"  Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 0 0 0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tipo}" FontWeight="Thin" FontSize="10" TextAlignment="Center"  />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Descrizione}" FontWeight="SemiBold" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel   Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical"  VerticalAlignment="Center"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 10" >
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Phone"  Margin="10 0 10 0"></SymbolIcon>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Telefono}"  />
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0 10 0 10">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Mail" Margin="10 0 10 0"></SymbolIcon>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Email}"  />
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

This is how use it:

```
                        <ListView x:Name="listaContatti"
                             IsItemClickEnabled="True" MaxHeight="200"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding ClientiContatti,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ListaClientiContatti,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                    <template:ItemTemplateContatti />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListViewItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
```

This is my result:
[image: image my result]

I would like to see the beginning of the line, the border blue color, and the two StackPanel so as you see in the visual studio designer:
[image: image my designer]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` of each `ListViewItem` to `Stretch`. Also set `Padding` to `0` to remove the gap before the blue bar.

```
<ListView x:Name="listaContatti"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True" MaxHeight="200"
    SelectedItem="{Binding ClientiContatti,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding ListaClientiContatti,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <template:ItemTemplateContatti />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: thanks, as well seem to work, however, the border tag, do not see it at the beginning but a few pixels further, why?

Comment: I've edited my answer with more information about this.